# Android debug and release APKs rendering views differently, and ProGuard is not enabled

Tags: android, debugging, view, release, proguard

My project.properties does not have ProGuard enabled. When I run a signed release APK, a `SurfaceView` in a transparent activity is composited with the underlying contents (not desired). However, when run from Eclipse in debug mode, the `SurfaceView` is not composited with the underlying contents (desired).

If no default ProGuard config is being run, I am fresh out of ideas on what could be different about my debug and release builds. If not ProGuard, what?

Comment: Is the release APK also running in Eclipse?

Comment: @fadden - No I create the release APK and sideload.

Comment: Any chance it's http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/30/yet-another-android-4-2-bug-weird-in-app-transparency-glitch-on-secondary-user-accounts/ ?